# Login with SSH user that has no password set

Tags: ssh, unix, login, passwd

I have a user without a password set (i.e. `passwd -d`).

I would not like to use public keys on this setup.

Is there a way to SSH login to such a user?

Comment: do you want to login as that user, or do you want to be sure that no one else logs in as that user?

Answer (score 26):

`PermitEmptyPasswords yes` then restart sshd ?

Comment: This works, but is horribly insecure.

Comment: For sure, but well, as said :
**I would not like to use public keys on this setup.**

Comment: With Ubuntu 13.10 `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` doesn't let the user with an empty password set login, even after a reboot.

Comment: @ProBackup you'll have to add `ssh` to `/etc/securetty` for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Allow `PermitEmptyPasswords` in `sshd_config` and restart `sshd`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to become the user in question, the simplest way is to log in as some other user (via ssh) and `su $username`. This requires root privilegies, but you could put the command in `/etc/sudoers` and only let your user execute that command as root.

If you really want to login through ssh (or remotely in some other way), you need to pick one of the following:

- Let anyone anywhere (or at least on the network you're on) login.
- Use a password to restrict who can login.
- Use certificates to restrict who can login. For ssh directly, this means a public/private key pair, either the ssh-style rsa pair or x509 (like for other ssl stuff).

Comment: This is a little confused: 1) `su` is not `sudo` 2) with `sudo` the "as root" does not apply.  While using `su` is an option, I (as a former Unix sysadmin) would rather see a focus on the use of `sudo`.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. 1) `sudo` does not look like logging in as or switching to a user, `su` does. The op wanted to log in as some user, not execute commands as it. 2) `sudo` lets you execute commands as another user (see `man sudo` if you don't believe me). In this case you would like to execute `su` *as root* to avoid having to give a password for the user you switch into. 3) Different tools for different tasks, although I guess some people have higher tolerances than me for typing `sudo -u postfix ` before their actual commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do **all** of the following:

- Set `PermitRootLogin yes` and `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` in
  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Set `StrictModes yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Add `ssh` to `/etc/securetty`
- `service ssh restart`

Comment: There's no reason to allow logging in as root using a password, as the OP did not say that they specifically wanted to be able to log in as root without a password.

Comment: Yes @9pfs, I agree. But to login without a password, I figured you need allow login as root (`PermitRootLogin yes`) AND empty passwords (`PermitEmptyPasswords yes`).