# Login to SSH with no password and no ssh-key?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

Mission : Let's say my remote server's `firewall` is configured to allow only my specific home `IP` to connect to `port 22` and because of this I am not worried about security for this test. And maybe I also plan on using a very complex username such as "user_name_82391274829"

Is it possible for me to `SSH` to my server like this ? :

```
ssh user_name_82391274829@server
server:/#
```

In other words, it simply logs in, 
without a password and without an ssh-key.

Note :
It should also work with `SCP`

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you not just use a key without a passphrase?

Comment: @davidgo, keys are encrypted, encrypted things confuse me because I have no understanding on how they are encrypted. If something is going to be encrypted, I want to be able to understand how it was encrypted. If the key was a simple text file that simply contained a non-encrypted password such as a really long password but could also be just a 6 character plain password, then I would probably use it. and if it has to be encrypted , I want to decide how to encrypt it. Maybe I could add `/encrypt.txt` to my server and write `1` in it, meaning every digit in the password should be `+1`.

Comment: Note: SSH communication is encrypted. Sorry, I guess you have `telnet` and `netcat` left. :D

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski, I am not happy about that either, once I figure how to get out of this `encrypted ssh-key` concept, I will be focusing on solving that issue also. I am definitely interested in a non-encrypted "ssh". I do not need security for anything other than the password.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Apologies, but if security is important to you you need to overcome your thinking. There is no good reason to have objectively bad security because you don't fully understand an aspect of encryption. Its difficult to point you in a clear direction without knowing exactly where your mental block is. Are you struggling with the concept of public/private key technology or something else?

Comment: @davidgo, I believe the rule of the universe is.. "If you do not understand something, you should not do it". I simply would like to build and run a web site, the only thing that needs to be kept secret is the password I use to log-in to my server. Everything else does not need to be kept a secret. The codes, the HTML, the whole world can see it, I just don't want anyone to log-in and delete or edit my files on the server that is all.

Comment: SSH is maintained to provide security even for users who don't understand what's under the hood. There's a consensus if you're not an expert in cryptography, the best you can do is to trust solutions provided by experts. Any custom solution will most likely be less secure. But you're not even trying to build some custom security; you're deliberately lowering the security. If you "don't want anyone to log-in and delete or edit your files" you should properly use SSH with all benefits it gives you.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski, Well, people that use things without understanding how they work, are probably breaking the rule of the universe which is " if you do not understand something, you should not do it " . Here in this country I am in of right now ( Turkey ), when you make a payment with a "visa" or "mastercard", an SMS verification is done for every payment, perhaps there can not be any higher security than that, even that can perhaps be "cracked" by someone that can create "SIM cards" and steal the signals from the satellites.

Comment: I guess you're a world-class expert in anatomy and physiology. Otherwise you would refrain from going to the toilet. :D If SSH breaks the rule of the Universe for you, learn. I'm not going to keep convincing you.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski, The only way to avoid going to the toilet is if a form of food is found that turns into energy in the body, and there are no leftovers that need to be discarded by the body. There are theories that it is possible to live with just sunlight and water, but I have not been able to test that because there is not much sunlight in the "housing" I live in.  Currently I eat mashed potatoes with dried-mint, garlic, and butter. I am definitely interested in stopping my butter consumption because I do not know how it is being made. ( or what it contains )

Comment: Here is the thing - we all use technology we only vaguely understand all the time - every day. You must have communicated your post from a computer/cellphone. There is no way anyone understands all the aspects of even how the CPU works, let Aline the intricacies of the transmission mechanisms. In fact by using SSH at all you are using things you don't understand. Similarly for your OS/kernel. You almost certainly don't farmall  your own food (its very hard), let alone make the tools from raw materials. You can't live off just sunlight and water. Not even plants can. (They need co2 etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1489019/432690) has many valid points. Read it because I won't repeat them. My answer is a practical guide.

1. Set an [empty password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472966/108618) on the server (I assume `user_name_82391274829` exists in the system; `chpasswd` needs root access):

   ```
   printf '%s\n' 'user_name_82391274829:U6aMy0wojraho' | chpasswd -e
   ```

   Note this is different from no password at all. After I set no password at all (`passwd -d user_name_82391274829`) the solution did not work, so stick to the above line with `chpasswd -e`.
2. Proper values in `sshd_config` on the server:

   ```
   PasswordAuthentication yes
   PermitEmptyPasswords yes
   ```

   Invoke `systemctl reload ssh.service` or equivalent command to reload `sshd`.

Tested on Debian 9.

Comment: It is a DES hash of the empty password. It could be a different kind of hash (e.g. sha1crypt or md5crypt), but it still needs to be a valid password hash.

Comment: Although, would it work if the password field were _completely empty_ (no hash at all)?

Comment: @grawity After `passwd -d user_name_82391274829` it did not work for me.

Comment: The comment in this answer https://superuser.com/a/384284/368397 says deleted password should also work with "add ssh to /etc/securetty"

Comment: You may also need to convince PAM to go along with this.  On NixOS I had to `security.pam.services.sshd.allowNullPassword = true;` to make this work (in addition to the stuff above).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible for me to SSH to my server like this [...] it simply logs in, without a password and without an ssh-key.

Yes, it's possible with OpenSSH at least, by disabling the requirement that passwords be non-empty in the server's sshd_config file.

> It should also work with SCP

SCP does not have its own authentication, it literally just calls `ssh` for the remote connection.

> my remote server's firewall is configured to allow only my specific home IP to connect to port 22 and because of this I am not worried about security for this test.

That's not a very good excuse – IP address is one of the weakest forms of authentication there is. For one, the server doesn't know whether the connection is made by your actual PC, or by an infected device on your home network, or by your guest/neighbour who is on your home Wi-Fi.

Linux firewalls are also more likely to fail open: if there's a syntax error in the ruleset, for example, it might revert back to allowing everything from everywhere on reboot. (Whereas if you make a mistake in authorized_keys it still doesn't allow anyone except valid key entries.)

> And maybe I also plan on using a very complex username such as "user_name_82391274829"

You just invented a password.

Comment: I un-commented these two options in the `sshd_config` file and changed their values. `PasswordAuthentication no `  .. `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` then I restarted the ssh server, this is the error I receive as I try to connect via ssh : `ssh: Connection to root@test:22 exited: No auth methods could be used.`

Comment: Hmm I think you need to keep password authentication enabled, even if it doesn't end up being used... And, obviously, make sure the account's password is indeed empty.

Comment: If I enable it, wouldn't it result in the `password prompt` showing up as I log-in via ssh ? I currently do not know how to set my password to empty because Linux will not allow it, however even if I made my password empty.. wouldn't there still be a password prompt which will be asking for an empty password ?

Comment: No, OpenSSH detects this situation and doesn't require auth in the first place.